# Get two string from a multilines data in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to get 2 string from multilines data. I used Reguler Expression to match the string that I want. First string is just one line, but the second is multipleline. This is my RegEx function

```
const RegExp = /\/Data first:(.*) second:(.*\n.*)/
const first = RegExp.exec(text)[1]
const second = RegExp.exec(text)[2]
```

I have the following string

```
/Data first:this first must include second:this second and
third
fourth
.
.
.
and so on must include
```

But it's not working as I expected. What I got is like this

```
first: this first line
second: this second
third
```

But I need to get result is like this

```
first: this first line
second: this second
third
fourth
.
.
.
and so on
```

I tried a lot of things, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `\/Data first:(.*) second:(.*[\s\S]*)`. I tested with your data and it's working as your requirement. You can try this playground.

https://regex101.com/r/a4bJIH/1